# Combinar C++ y Python

Tags: python, c++

A la hora de crear interfaces gráficas con C++ lo veo un mundo, y he estado leyendo la posibilidad de combinar dos lenguajes, uno de ellos C++. 
Mi pregunta es, ¿se podría hacer todo lo esencial con c++ pero la parte grafica con Python? Es decir, dos archivos separados pero que se hagan referencia uno a otro.

Answer (score 5):

Es bastante común que se integren módulos de extensión escritos en ***c/c++*** en bibliotecas Python, sobretodo cuando se necesita mucha eficiencia o usar recursos o bibliotecas ya existentes. Librerías para calculo científico, big-data, etc como Pandas, NumPy, 
SciPy, bibliotecas para creación de GUI (interacción con OpenGL, Qt, GTK...), etc usan esto muy a menudo. Las mismas técnicas permiten que se interactúe con partes escritas en C del kernel Linux, por ejemplo.

A esto se le conoce como ***"wrapping"*** (envolver). Hay múltiples formas desde simplemente llamar funciones ***c/c++*** desde un modulo o biblioteca estática hasta usar código compilado en librerías dinámicas (***.so*** y ***.dll***). Existen diferentes formas de conseguir integrar el código:

- En CPython (implementación oficial y mas común) se puede:

  - Usar la [API Python/C](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/).
  - Utilizar el módulo [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) (biblioteca estándar) o [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

  Se puede encontrar mas información al respecto en [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html) de la documentación oficial de Python.
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).
- [Boost-Python](http://www.boost.org/)
- [SIP](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/using.html)
- Usar [Cython](http://cython.org/) (compilador estático para Python)

Otra opción es compilar a ejecutable, ejecutar cada proceso por separado y comunicar/controlar ambos procesos usando [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) por ejemplo.

En definitiva, es posible combinar código de ***c++*** con una biblioteca o aplicación hecha en Python (también al contrario) y existen múltiples opciones para ello. Va a depender de las características propias del proyecto, bibliotecas a usar y de las necesidades concretas que se tengan.

Comment: Entonces, si yo creara una interfaz grafica en Python usando Tkinter (porque es el que más fácil veo), podría hacer llamadas a funciones de un archivo .cpp cuando presionara un botón, por ejemplo?

Comment: Estoy tratando de implementar un sencillo ejemplo, pero me da errores. He tratado con visual studio y con mingw. En visual studio he linkado Python como sale en las guias, y en mingw he instalado las librerias en la carpeta de mingw, incluyo la cabecera <Python.h> y me da error. Con mingw me da el error "::hypot has not been declared" y en visual studio me da el error "error LNK1104: no se puede abrir el archivo 'python36_d.lib'"