# ¿Puedo insertar código C en python?

Tags: python, c

quería saber si alguno sabe si se puede usar código de C en python. En la escuela me pidieron dos lenguajes para programar y ya tengo 3 autómatas en C, pero necesito gráficar. Entonces apenas voy iniciando en python así que quería ver si había una forma de solo insertar mi código de C. Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Si te dijera que **"no"** supongo que lo tomarías como una respuesta demasiado corta. ¿Está el código compilado?¿obtienes algún resultado intermedio que sirva para hacer la gráfica?¿Has mirado la [documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) sobre el tema? Por favor, completa la pregunta, a ser posible con algún ejemplo que nos sirva de orientación.

Comment: Parece que si, aunque no directamente. Aquí te dejo un par de sitios que hablan de ello. https://www.enchufa2.es/archives/utilizar-funciones-y-tipos-de-c-en-python.html https://shakaran.net/blog/2010/10/como-usar-bibliotecas-de-c-en-python/

Comment: Tienes la respuesta en nuestro "hermano" en lengua inglesa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541265/embed-c-in-python

Comment: @Peppo la gracia de SOes es disponer de contenido en español... para tirar de SOen entonces cerramos SOes y tan contentos

Answer (score 11):

No puedes insertar código C en un script de Python como tal. El código C debe ser compilado como es lógico. Lo que si es relativamente simple es extender Python con código C compilado usando por norma general librerias de enlace dinámico (`.so`, `dll`, etc).

Hacer esto en Python es posible usando solo la biblioteca estándar de Python y un compilador de C. Hay dos opciones, usas la biblioteca [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html) (muy fácil de usar pero menos flexible), o directamente la [`API Python/C`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) (bastante más compleja pero mucho más flexible y poderosa).

Tienes muy buenos manuales de ambos métodos en la documentación estándar, para completar la respuesta voy a dejar dos ejemplos simplificados de como usar una función muy simple de C en Python.

> **Nota:** En el ejemplo se va a usar un entorno Linux con gcc 7.2.0
>    como compilador y Python 3.6.

Imaginemos nuestra función de C para calcular el factorial, algo como:

```
unsigned long long _factorial(int n) {
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

Bien, vamos a ver como extender Python con este código:

- **Usando ctypes:**

  1. **Creamos un archivo `factorial.c`** que contiene nuestra función.
  2. **Compilamos nuestro código** para crear una librería de enlace dinámico (situándonos en el directorio del archivo fuente):

     ```
      $ gcc -shared -W -o libfactorial.so factorial.o
     ```

  Esto nos crea un fichero *shared object* llamado `libfactorial.so`.

  3. Ahora que hemos terminado con C vamos a **crear un wrapper con ctypes** para poder usar la librería de C con Python y poder llamar sus funciones:

     ```
     # Importamos la librería ctypes
     import ctypes

     # Cargamos la libreria 
     libfactorial = ctypes.CDLL('./libfactorial.so')

     # Definimos los tipos de los argumentos de la función factorial
     libfactorial.factorial.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)

     # Definimos el tipo del retorno de la función factorial
     libfactorial.factorial.restype = ctypes.c_ulonglong

     # Creamos nuestra función factorial en Python
     # hace de Wrapper para llamar a la función de C
     def factorial(num):
         return libfactorial.factorial(num)
     ```

  Con esto hemos terminado. Ya podemos importar nuestro módulo y llamar a la función de C como si de código Python se tratara:

  ```
      >>> from factorial import factorial
      >>> print(factorial(11))
      39916800
  ```
- **Usando la API Python/C:**

  Como ya comenté, esto es trabajar a más bajo nivel, por lo que es más complejo. Es una forma muy común de distribuir librerias que requieren de código C compilado por razones de eficiencia o de reutilización de código.

  1. **Empezamos por el código fuente de C (`factorial.c`):**

     ```
     #include <Python.h>

     unsigned long long _factorial(int n)
     {
     unsigned long long result = 1;
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
         result *= i;
     return result;
     }

     // Wrapper para Python de la función factorial
     static PyObject* factorial(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
     {
         // Declaramos los argumentos de entrada
         int num;

         //  Parseamos los argumentos de entrada, de int en Python a int de C
         if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &num))
             return NULL;
             /*En el caso de pasar argumentos incorrectos la funcion retornara NULL
             y una excepcion apropiada sera retornada por el intérprete*/
         return Py_BuildValue("K", _factorial(num));
         /*Debemos retornar un objeto Python, en este caso un entero
           "K" se corresponde con el tipo unsigned long long
           ver: https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue*/
     }

     // Definimos las funciones del módulo
     static PyMethodDef factorial_Methods[] =
     {
          {"factorial", factorial, METH_VARARGS, "Muestra el factorial de un numero dado"},
          {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
     };

     /*Struct con la definicion del modulo, 
      Contiene toda la información necesaria para crear el objeto */
     static struct PyModuleDef factorialmod =
     {
         PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
         "factorial", /* name of module */
         "",          /* module documentation, may be NULL */
         -1,          /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
         factorial_Methods
     };

      // Inicializacion del modulo
     PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_factorial(void)
     {
         return PyModule_Create(&factorialmod);
     }
     ```
  2. **Creamos nuestro `setup.py`** que permitirá la instalación del módulo al ejecutarlo usando `distutils`:

     ```
     from distutils.core import setup, Extension

     # Definimos el modulo de extension
     factorial_module = Extension('factorial', sources=['factorial.c'])

     # Ejecutar el setup
     setup(ext_modules=[factorial_module])
     ```
  3. Hemos terminado. Solo queda **instalar el módulo**:

     ```
     $ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
     ```

     Esto nos creará una biblioteca de enlace dinámico con un nombre similar a `factorial.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` y que podemos importar y usar igual que antes con `ctypes`.

El ejemplo es muy simple por no hacer la respuesta aún más extensa, pero la idea es esta. Existen otras alternativas fuera de la biblioteca estándar, puedes mirarte mi respuesta a la pregunta [Combinar C++ y Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99605/15089) en donde doy un listado de algunas de las herramientas disponibles. En este caso se pregunta por C++ pero las herramientas son las mismas en principio. Lo que si es cierto es que por lo general es mucho mas simple extender con C que con C++ (por ejemplo `ctypes` no acepta C++ sin usar un wrapper con C).