# ¿Transferir datos entre C++ y Python?

Tags: python, c++

estoy trabajando en un proyecto para la universidad en c++, este trata de simular un sistema de matricula. El programa era trabajado sólo por modo consola. Ahora necesito desarrollar una interfaz gráfica, pero la interfaz debe ser hecha en python.

Mi pregunta es, como comunicar python y c++, como puedo utilizar las funciones que tengo en el archivo c++, pedir datos y tomarlos desde python para proyectarlos, además de que la ejecució del programa debe hacerse desde c++.
He investigado un poco de la C/Python api, de cython, cpython, pero no encuentro en la documentación algo relacionado directamente a mi problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Leonardo verifica este enlace, que creo es lo que estás buscando .... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99605/combinar-c-y-python

Comment: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Combinar C++ y Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99605/combinar-c-y-python)